# Trying to calculate the number of working days from a given date and to exclude weekends in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select a column that would reference a date-time value and allow me to find the date given an addition or subtraction of weekdays from the referenced date. I know I can calculate the number of days between with DateDiff but that hasn't seemed as useful in trying to determine a landing date X number of days from a given reference. Is there a way of leveraging DATE_ADD or another function for this?

Comment: You could probably come up with a formula that takes into account the number of days between the two dates, the day of the week of the first date, and how many weekend days are in between. However, we'd have to see your exact query to help you come up with that formula. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71375121/edit) to show us your SQL statement so far.

Comment: If you provide some testing data & your required result, it will be helpful for us.